# Mahapps custom style error

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, nuget-package, mahapps.metro

I want to set a Custom Style in my Applications,
but when i try the MahApps tutorial from:

http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html

I get this Error:
[image]

"The property Freeze was not found in type 'SolidColorBrush'"

**My Question is:**

Which CLR must I declare for the Freeze Option ?

Comment: I've updated the styles guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clr for the Freeze Declaration is:

```
xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options
```